# Extension of Spring Authorization Server to handle FAPI (Financial-grade API)

Tags: spring-authorization-server

I have been working through the excellent **spring-authorization-server** examples [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples).

This has been superb for understanding **oauth2** via a working model.

However, the current requirements are to handle the [Financial-grade API or **'FAPI'**](https://openid.net/wg/fapi/) protocols.

Are there any plans to extend spring-authorization-server to include **FAPI** support, and if so, do you have a broad timeline of when it might be available ?

Many Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of related issues ([search](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20fapi)) already in the issue tracker, but there is not currently a theme/epic tracking full support. There are a couple of things to think about and you can open issues based on any of these that make sense:

- missing specific features (like PAR, JAR, etc. though these already have issues opened)
- missing extension points that would allow customizing the auth server to support specific profiles, specifications or features
- holistic support for finalized FAPI specifications (Part 1, Part 2, JARM, etc.)

We typically prioritize features based on upvotes on GitHub issues, so opening issues for anything you feel is needed is a good first step. The more details you can provide, the better. Also, being able to provide additional information or research on other providers that already provide the support you're seeking is very helpful.